# architecture help with a website in php

Tags: php, mysql, architecture

I am helping to make a website in PHP which is an ERP purpose website. We made mockups of a form to collect user details which is split into 4 screens facebook style where the end user keeps clicking next after filling in each partial form. Finally they get the preview and confirmation receipt is generated.
How should I go about this in the backend, I am sure that after the preview I will write the values to the Mysql db and generate a receipt. My question is how do I go about storing the values before the preview?

Comment: Try to explain your problem better, so we can help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot really answer your question in isolation. It really depends on how your user is going to use the system, whether the information they enter should be persistent, and even whether you know who the user is?

Assuming you know who the user is, and you want to keep failed sessions, my suggestion would be to store the partial responses in a database so you can always access them later.

You can then populate or re-populate the form as you wish. You should also have a "start again" button in this scenario.

More information would help give a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use php sessions to store the variables in a session and then at the end store them all in the database.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Answer (score 0):

You can just have one form per screen/page and send these values as parameters to the next page via post or get - it's the most simple way

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to keep all the form markup on single page and divide form into steps using formToWizard jquery plugin. 
http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/09/28/webform-wizard-jquery.aspx

This way user has all data available when users clicks and back and forth during the steps and you can just have single submit button.